# MFMailComposeViewController - load images inside the html

Tags: iphone, html, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I created an `MFMailComposeViewController`. I attached some files using `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:`. The files are attached successfully.

The HTML in the message body has the following code:

```
<IMG border="0" style="border:0;" src="fileName.gif" >
```

I'm adding the attachment data with the same file name, but it isn't being loaded in the HTML. I just get a blue box with a question mark. Is there anything else I need to do in order to load the images? I'm following the documentation:

```
If you want to include images with your content, 
you must attach the images separately using the 
addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName: method.
You should call this method before you display the mail composition interface 
only. Do not call it after presenting the interface to the user.
```

Comment: What are you using for the mime type? Also, if you try using PNGs instead of GIFs do you get the same result?

Comment: image/gif. I'll try with a PNG file, but I need it to work for GIFs...

Comment: I've found this, but it is a complex solution: http://twoshotsofcocoa.com/?p=20

Comment: I asked because I believe Mobile Safari has issues/doesn't support GIFs (*especially animated ones*) and since Mail will use Mobile Safari as its rendering engine this is where the issue may stem from. However, if you get the same result using PNGs then it's obviously something else at fault.

Comment: That solution at twoshotsofcocoa.com/?p=20 wont work for gmail and others.  The message comes through, but the image will not be displayed.